# Create a single executable file containing multiple python's Tkinter module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have two windows, one main and one sub-window, and their codes are as follow:

`main.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

root = tk.Tk()

def openwindow():
    # root.destroy()
    os.startfile("window.py")

root_b = tk.Button(root, text="Open window", command=openwindow)
root_b.grid(row=1, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

`window.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window_l = tk.Label(window, text="Window 1")
window_l.grid(row=0, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Using the [Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org) module, I tried to combine them into a single executable program using the code:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py window.py
```

However, clicking the button on main.py gives the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'test2.py'

And after closing the main window, the sub-window will pop out.

My question is how do I combine both file into single executable program?

Using Python 3.

Comment: what is test2.py?

Comment: Sorry for that. It should be window.py

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are opposed to refactoring your code then you could make it work with:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "./window.py;." main.py
```

However you could simply refactor you code as well like so:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

root = tk.Tk()

def new_window():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window_l = tk.Label(window, text="Window 1")
    window_l.grid(row=0, column=0)
    window.mainloop()
    

def openwindow():
    root.destroy()
    new_window()

root_b = tk.Button(root, text="Open window", command=openwindow)
root_b.grid(row=1, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Then you have everything in one file and you can simply use.

```
pyinstaller -F main.py
```

And bob's your uncle